# Plotly: How to create a table with no header?

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to create a table in Plotly (Python) with no header. The table only has two columns, which are essentially "parameter name" and "parameter value", so displaying the explicit column names seems clunky. I am able to create a table with blank column names in the header, but what I really want is a table with only the values.

I have searched the documentation, but was not able to find a way to do this. I tried creating the table without a header object and with `header=None`, but both of these produce a table with an empty header.

Is it possible to create a table in Plotly without a header, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The headers will still exist, but you can make them very invisible like this:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(header_fill_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
```

Or:

```
fig.layout['template']['data']['table'][0]['header']['fill']['color']='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
```

Here's a complete example that builds on the first example in [plot.ly/python/table](https://plot.ly/python/table/)

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))])

fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(header_fill_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
fig.layout['template']['data']['table'][0]['header']['fill']['color']='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
fig.show()
```

This assumes that you're building a plot without any lines between the cells.
But you could always make them disappear the same way. I hope this is what you were looking for. If not, then don't hesitate to let me know.